# How lookup anchor tag <a> by attribute name and/or value?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

This is the web that I am trying to automate:

https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/sweatshirts/xi9sboa21/u2te1fdw8
[image: imagen]

My requirement is to click on the image depending on the color entered as input. For example, if "red" is entered as input I must click in the **red** sweatshirt like the previous picture.

Target images are in `<li><a>`:

```
<ul class="styles">
   <li><a class="" data-images="..." data-style-name="Red" data-style-id="22898" href="...">
     <img src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/168724/sw/RymAY-fhCvA.jpg" alt="Rymay fhcva" width="32" height="32"></a>
   </li>
   <li><a class="" data-images="..." data-style-name="Natural" data-style-id="22899" href="...">
     <img src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/168722/sw/P9adXZbmQQ4.jpg" alt="P9adxzbmqq4" width="32" height="32"></a>
   </li>
   <li><a class="" data-images="..." data-style-name="Navy" data-style-id="22900" href="...">
     <img src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/168723/sw/nC1YwBFpU5g.jpg" alt="Nc1ywbfpu5g" width="32" height="32"></a>
   </li>
   <li><a class="" data-images="..." data-style-name="Black" data-style-id="22901" href="...">
     <img src="//assets.supremenewyork.com/168721/sw/viAmPE40S9U.jpg" alt="Viampe40s9u" width="32" height="32"></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

In the **data-style-name="Red"** attribute.

I tried with this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@itemprop="model">{}</p>]'.format(color.get()))
```

But it does not seem to find it.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask questions.

Comment: What is your requirement? Get the string "Navy" from <p class="style protect" itemprop="model">Navy</p> ??

Comment: So in my program using Tkinter tools user inputs item and colorway. It takes him to the link with the item (which I have figured out how to do), but then I am not sure how to grab that colorway. A user has already defined it, for example, the color is "Natural", by his definition, so how do I locate it and click the right picture with the right color? Not get the string, but kind of locate it and click it, if it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: But yes, it is located in the itemprop part. How do I get to it and click() it ?

Comment: I think your question must be : "How lookup <a> by text and click it ?" Are you agree?

Comment: Yeah, that way might also work I guess.  Problem is  that by changing pictures, this is what changes <p class="style protect" itemprop="model">Black</p>  (the color changes inside). But maybe you have a better solution )

Answer (score 0):

Here some approaches:

- You can lookup the `<a>` who has `data-style-name=YourColor` using xpath:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@data-style-name="Red"]')
```

- Loop through the all `<a>` and compare the **data-style-name** attribute value with the input color:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@href]")
for elem in elems:
    print elem.get_attribute("data-style-name")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use following XPath :**

**XPATH :** //p[@class='style protect' and normalize-space()='"+COLOR_VALUE_VARIABLE+"']

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//p[@class='style protect' and normalize-space()='"+COLOR_VALUE_VARIABLE+"']")
```